# Image view is not clickable In viewholder

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I don't get why `onclick` is not working on image. I tried to add `clickable` and `focusable`, but no luck.

my Xml having image view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/messengerImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_36dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/incoming_layout_bubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/balloon_incoming_normal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:text="Receiver"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/messageTextView"
                android:id="@+id/messengerTextView"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_time"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="11:15 PM"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                style="@style/chat_timings"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_36dp"
                android:contentDescription="send_photo"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/videoview"
                android:contentDescription="send_video"
                android:src="@drawable/videoiconcrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
            />

            <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconTextView
                android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text="Rahul Agrawal is a good boy but he does not know what he wants."
                style="@style/chat_text_message_style"
                emojicon:emojiconSize="30sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notacceptmedia"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/notacceptmedia" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/acceptmedia"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My viewHolder:

```
public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public EmojiconTextView messageTextView;
    public TextView messengerTextView;
    public CircleImageView messengerImageView;
    public ImageView sendimage;
    public ImageView videoview;
    public TextView messageTime;
    public ImageView acceptmedia;
    public ImageView notacceptmedia;

    public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        messageTextView = (EmojiconTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
        messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
        sendimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        videoview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        messageTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
        acceptmedia =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acceptmedia);
        notacceptmedia = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notacceptmedia);
    }
}
```

Code to implement onclick on imageView:

```
viewHolder.acceptmedia.setClickable(true);
//viewHolder.acceptmedia.setFocusable(true);
viewHolder.acceptmedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(GroupChatScreen.this, "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("test","Accept");
    }
});
viewHolder.notacceptmedia.setClickable(true);
//viewHolder.notacceptmedia.setFocusable(true);
viewHolder.notacceptmedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(GroupChatScreen.this, "Decline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("test","Decline");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am wondering about your use of `itemView` in the `ViewHolder` and why you aren't using `v`. Can you post more of your adapter and `ViewHolder` code? Especially anything dealing with `itemView`?

Answer (score 0):

you may Use image button instead of image view.
Hope this will solve your problem.